# Can I add a css style in the formula editor in crystal report

Tags: css, crystal-reports

In crystal report:

right click on a field -> edit formula. I can add some html elements.

example

```
 <u>
 IF {myobject.myfield} = "something" THEN
       blabla1
 ELSE
       blabla2
 </u>
```

Is there a way to add a css font style?

I would like to underline the whole line. Not only where there is text

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
IF {myobject.myfield} = "something" THEN
       <u>blabla1</u>
 ELSE
       </u>blabla2</u>
```

But that would require turning on the 'Interpret as HTML option.
Why not simply format the formula object with underline?

Comment: I want to underline the whole line. Not only where there is words. therefore I need to add  a css style

Answer (score 0):

Even with a CSS style, it will still only underline the text and will not extend the underline beyond.

I see two other ways to accomplish this though.

1. Make the field the entire width of the area that you want to be underlined, then add a bottom border to the field or text object.
2. Use the line drawing tool to add a horizontal line to the report where it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't give a solution to the mentioned problem. But it give a solution to the problem that leads to this problem, i.e., underline the whole line.

select the feld, click on underline. In "edit formula", add space(N) before each line break. With N is a big number